# Create test case name (using JUnitParams) from an array passed as a parameter

Tags: java, junit, junitparams

Is there a way to print contents of an array (passed as one of test parameters) using the `@TestCaseName` annotation?

What I mean is that I want this test case

```
private static final File JAVA_DIRECTORY = get("src/main/java/").toFile();
private static final String[] NOT_ACCEPTABLE_IN_JAVA_DIRECTORY = {"groovy", "css", "html"};

public Object[] filesNotAcceptedInDirectories() {
    return $(
            $(JAVA_DIRECTORY, NOT_ACCEPTABLE_IN_JAVA_DIRECTORY)
    );
}

@Test
@Parameters(method = "filesNotAcceptedInDirectories")
@TestCaseName("Verify that no files with extensions {1} are present in directory {0}")
public void verifyFilesArePlacedInAppropriateDirectories(File directory, String[] unacceptableFiles) {
    assertThat(listFiles(directory, unacceptableFiles, true)).isEmpty();
}
```

to display as

> Verify that no files with extensions [groovy, css, html] are present in directory src\main\java

What I currently get is

> Verify that no files with extensions String[] are present in directory src\main\java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible once the new version is released (1.0.5) - https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/issues/70

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's not possible at the moment. The part that stringifies the parameter is `junitparams.internal.Utils#addParamToResult`:

```
private static String addParamToResult(String result, Object param) {
    if (param == null)
        result += "null";
    else {
        try {
            tryFindingOverridenToString(param);
            result += param.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result += param.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static void tryFindingOverridenToString(Object param)
        throws NoSuchMethodException {
    final Method toString = param.getClass().getMethod("toString");

    if (toString.getDeclaringClass().equals(Object.class)) {
        throw new NoSuchMethodException();
    }
}
```

You can see that only in case when the parameter overrides the `Object#toString` that overridden `toString` is used, otherwise it's just class simple name, which in case of a String array is `String[]`.